# GLU_TESS_WINDING_NONZERO for apple Metal

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

Does anyone know a property like GLU_TESS_WINDING_NONZERO for MetalKit?
I want to add this effect in my drawing app, however in MetalKit there is no property like glu_tess_winding.

Comment: Given that all of the GLU_TESS stuff is pretty old, slow, and bad in general, there probably isn't. Tessellation is something you'll have to implement yourself.